# Error on php XML DOM

Tags: php, xml, xmldom

I got an error that I can't solve.

```
$unsortedArray = array (array ( 'profileId' => '32', 'profileMiniature' => '32' ,'firstName' => 'Sarmad', 'lastName' => 'Nekomanesh', 'numberOfMutualContacts' => '0' ), array ( 'profileId' => '37', 'profileMiniature' => '37', 'firstName' => 'Sophie', 'lastName' => 'Gronlund', 'numberOfMutualContacts' => '0' ) );

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');


foreach($unsortedArray as $v){
    $profiles = $xml->createElement('profiles');
    $xml->appendChild($profiles);
    $profile = $xml->createElement('profile');
    $profile->setAttribute('profileId', $v['profileId']);
    $profile->setAttribute('profileMiniature', $v['profileMiniature']);
    $profile->setAttribute('firstName', $v['firstName']);
    $profile->setAttribute('lastName', $v['lastName']);
    $profiles->appendChild($profile);
}


$xml->formatOutput = true;
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

And when I only got one array element in the array I got no error at all.

Comment: This page contains the following errors:

error on line 5 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: any clue on what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your lines of code (copy&paste) and got no errors. It printed valid XML document. You probably have errors in other code.

Comment: maybe some wrong with my php version than. I copy paste it and still got the error.

Comment: May be the problem is: no root XML-tag. Yep! get the line $profiles = $xml->createElement('profiles'); out of foreach circle. Place it before foreach.

Comment: yes a very newbie mistake a made:) I've done this a thousand times and never mistaken

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
$xml->formatOutput = false;
```

or **echo** command. And look, there is any error.

Comment: saveXML() returns XML and output file.So, you can't echo it. You have to set output options correctly, and when you use saveXML() , XML saved to a file (for example).